# Prevent scanning of the Apache's /default directory

Tags: apache-2.2, ddos

I have two directories, under */var/www/vhosts*: *mydomain/* and *default/*. Files in default directory can be accessed using IP address of our server.

I have checked Apache log and somebody is constantly, trying to access random files under that directory - is performing "mapping". Also IP address, from which request is coming appears always different in Apache's error log. I have also a suspicion that this mapping causes Apache to run out of available slots, and jam at the end.

Here is a snippet from Apache log:

```
[Mon May 14 16:04:04 2012] [error] [client 190.12.83.230] File does not exist: /var/www/vhosts/default/htdocs/manager
[Mon May 14 16:05:29 2012] [error] [client 200.48.7.17] File does not exist: /var/www/vhosts/default/htdocs/manager
[Mon May 14 16:19:12 2012] [error] server reached MaxClients setting, consider raising the MaxClients setting
```

Is there any way to prevent these attacks?

Answer (score 1):

You can install and configure fail2ban to block access for ips that generates those kind of errors.

here are some helpful links

http://www.the-art-of-web.com/system/fail2ban/

http://richardjh.org/blog/blocking-brute-force-attacks-to-dovecot-on-centos/

http://www.fail2ban.org/wiki/index.php/MANUAL_0_8

Comment: Thank you for linking to my site but you have linked to a dynamic link on richardjh.org used for paging results. The contant on that page will change as posts are added. Perhaps You meant to use http://richardjh.org/blog/blocking-brute-force-attacks-to-dovecot-on-centos/. I have edited you answer to use this URL I hope that is ok.

Answer (score 1):

Why do you think that these scans cause apache to run out of available slots?

I suggest that instead of hunting a phantom, you first configure [mod_status](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_status.html) to find out what URLs are being processed by your server. You can then decide what action you want to take.